# How to trim a video recorded from mobile or picked from gallery.

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, trim

Java android video ffmpeg trim
I want to trim a video just like trimmed in whatsapp, instagram or vine, where user can select the duration from below showing trim bar.

I am also using FFMPEG, so once user selects the duration. But FFMPEG 
integartions are not going smooth. If any idea than leme know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you are finding ffmpeg hard to integrate then its worth being aware there are different ways to integrate ffmpeg, and one common way which is probably easiest is you simply want to get the functionality working quickly is to use a 'wrapper' around the ffmpeg command line exec.

There are several fairly well used wrappers available on GitHub - the ones below are particularly well featured and documented (note, I have not used these as they were not so mature when I was looking at this previously, but if I was doing something like this again now I would definitely build on one of these):

- http://hiteshsondhi88.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/
- https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg

Because this approach uses the standard ffmpeg cmd line syntax for commands it also means you should be able to search and find help easily on multiple different operations (as anyone using ffmpeg in 'normal' model will use the same syntax for the ffmpeg command itself).

Answer (score 3):

Using ffmpeg , it has a very restrictive license that requires your app to also be open sourced and have its license, as I remember. Plus it takes a lot of code space as I remember.

If you wish, you can use [**VideoTrimmer**](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/VideoTrimmer) library I've made, which is based on others.

Comment: FFmpeg is licensed LGPL 2.1 or later, or GPL 2.0 or later: depending on how you configured it.

Comment: Doesn't using it mean that your app has to be open sourced and with the same license too? Which library for Android exactly uses FFmpeg that allows to avoid this?

Comment: That's a broad question and it depends on which license you're using and if you are distributing anything from FFmpeg with your app.

Comment: OK suppose all I want to do is to trim the video (like in the title of this question thread), and publish the app without publishing its code (meaning closed source). Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, with the LGPL, assuming you follow the terms of the license.

Comment: @llogan OK, so where can I find such a library for Android? And what are the things to worry about using such a library, in terms of legality and technical usage?

Comment: You can find the source code at ffmpeg.org. For legality see: https://ffmpeg.org/legal.html (and it depends where you reside). I can't comment on what technical things to worry about without any details. You should be post this as a new question on this site.

Comment: @llogan I asked about Android. Isn't the ffmpeg huge for an Android app? I remember there were alternatives that are based on it, which are more suited for Android... Also, it is said there everywhere to be careful of using this library for commercial apps... So I don't think this is a safe thing to use.

Comment: I don't know anything about Android.

Comment: I was commenting about ffmpeg.

Comment: @llogan I was saying it might be a bad choice for Android apps, and offered either the build in framework or a different library...